# Django query based on another query results

Tags: django

I have 4 models in my simplified design

```
class modelA(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()

class modelsUser(model.Model):
     username = models.CharField()

class bridge(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(modelUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bridges')
     modelA = models.ForeignKey(modelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bridges')

class subModelA(models.Model):
     modelA = models.ForeignKey(modelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subModelAs')
     value = models.IntegerField()

class subModelB(models.Model):
     modelA = models.ForeignKey(modelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subModelBs')
     text = models.TextField()
```

What I am trying to to is to get all `subModelB`s and `subModelA`s that are for `modelA`s for which given `modelUser` have `bridge`.

I've started with this:

```
user = modelUser.objects.get(pk=1)
bridges = user.bridges.all()
```

What I've been thinking is something like this:

```
subModelBs = subModelB.objects.filter(modelA__in=bridges__modelA)
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work because of error that `__modelA is not defined`.

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: ```subModelBs = subModelB.objects.filter(modelA__in=user.bridges.all().values_list("modelA", flat=True))```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find first the `modelAs` and then do two other queries:

```
modelAs = bridge.objects.filter(user__pk=1).values_list('modelA', flat=True)

subModelAs = subModelA.object.filter(modelA__in=modelAs)
subModelBs = subModelB.object.filter(modelA__in=modelAs)
```

Answer (score 1):

A good question first of all!

Tried reproducing on my system, the following worked for me:

```
user = modelUser.objects.get(pk=1)
bridges = user.bridges.all()
subModelAs = subModelA.objects.filter(
    modelA_id__in=[x.modelA_id for x in list(bridges)]
)
```

And similarly for subModelBs. Hope this helps you well.